# Arduino Uno and Johnny-Five stops after few seconds

Tags: javascript, arduino, johnny-five

I am using Arduino Uno, Node.js and Johnny-Five for one of my projects. When I try to run the [code below](https://github.com/rwaldron/johnny-five/wiki/Ping) everything works just fine, I get the feedback from the sensor. **After few seconds the Node.js just stops not giving me any reason.** I tested the code on Ubuntu and Node runs infinitely but not on Windows 7. Do you know any troubleshooting technique that will help me identify why Node.js stops? Many thanks.

```js
var five = require("johnny-five");
var board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {

  // Create a new `ping` hardware instance.
  var ping = new five.Ping(7);

  // ping.in
  //
  // Calculated distance to obstruction in inches
  //

  // ping.cm
  //
  // Calculated distance to obstruction in centimeters
  //

  ping.on("change", function(err, value) {
    console.log("Object is " + this.in + "inches away");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you try this modified version: http://johnny-five.io/examples/proximity-hcsr04/ and let me know if that makes a difference—thanks!